# Line fitting below points

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a set of x, y points and I'd like to find the line of best fit such that the line is below all points using SciPy. I'm trying to use leastsq for this, but I'm unsure how to adjust the line to be below all points instead of the line of best fit. The coefficients for the line of best fit can be produced via:

```
def linreg(x, y):

    fit = lambda params, x: params[0] * x - params[1]
    err = lambda p, x, y: (y - fit(p, x))**2 

    # initial slope/intercept
    init_p = np.array((1, 0))

    p, _ = leastsq(err, init_p.copy(), args=(x, y))

    return p

xs = sp.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])  
ys = sp.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])

print linreg(xs, ys)
```

The output is the coefficients for the line of best fit:

```
array([  9.99999997e+00,  -1.68071668e-15])
```

How can I get the coefficients of the line of best fit that is below all points?

Comment: This seems like more of a math question than a programming one.  Try asking at http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I'm fairly certain of the math. This problem requires minimizing the `fit` function such that all points on the line of best fit are < y. I'm uncertain as to how to implement this in SciPy.

Comment: Minimizing the error between each data point and the line of best fit will necessarily mean that some data points will be above and some will be below the line.  Are you just trying to find the line of best fit, and then adjust the y-intercept so that the line passes below all of the data points?

Comment: I think the OP wants to find a line of best fit that is under all data points.

Comment: this is difficult -- the best fit line will definitely go through one of the points in the dataset forming the convex hull

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible algorithm is as follows:

1. Move the axes to have all the data  on the positive half of the x axis.
2. If the fit is of the form `y = a * x + b`, then for a given `b` the best fit for `a` will be the minimum of the slopes joining the point `(0, b)` with each of the `(x, y)` points.
3. You can then calculate a fit error, which is a function of only `b`, and use `scipy.optimize.minimize` to find the best value for `b`.
4. All that's left is computing `a` for that `b` and calculating `b` for the original position of the axes.

The following does that most of the time, except when the minimization fails with some mysterious error:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fit_below(x, y) :
    idx = np.argsort(x)
    x = x[idx]
    y = y[idx]
    x0, y0 = x[0] - 1, y[0]
    x -= x0
    y -= y0

    def error_function_2(b, x, y) :
        a = np.min((y - b) / x)
        return np.sum((y - a * x - b)**2)

    b = scipy.optimize.minimize(error_function_2, [0], args=(x, y)).x[0]

    a = np.min((y - b) / x)

    return a, b - a * x0 + y0

x = np.arange(10).astype(float)
y = x * 2 + 3 + 3 * np.random.rand(len(x))

a, b = fit_below(x, y)

plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.plot(x, a*x + b, '-')
plt.show()
```

And as TheodrosZelleke wisely predicted, it goes through two points that are part of the convex hull:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly was I was trying to do.